# tpm_crb MSFT0101 :00: can't request for ressource [mem 0xddd 7b000-0xddd7efff]

Tags: dual-boot, lenovo

every time i start ubuntu i get this error message "[     0.449310] tpm_crb MSFT0101 :00: can't request for ressource [mem 0xddd 7b000-0xddd7efff]

/dev/sda5: clean, 227944/6406144 files, 4261898/25600000 blocks"
after showing this message, ubuntu starts normally, someone help me to fix that problem